# I can't get the Jackson object mapper to set the type correctly

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, json-serialization

I have this json:

```
{
 "List": [
  {
   "Field1": 1678493915,
   "Field2": "A string"
  }
 ]
}
```

When I define this method in a helper class:

```
  public static Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> readJSON(String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
      return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<>() {});
  }
```

The field `Field1` is parsed as a String as I want. But I want to make the method generic enough to be used in other places so I wrote this one in the helper class:

```
  public static <T> T readJSON2(String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
      return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<>(){});
  }
```

And I called:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> data = readJSON2(jsonString);
```

Unluckily in this case `Field1` is parsed as an Integer.

I can do the following in the helper class:

```
  public static <T> T readJSON3(String json, TypeReference<T> typeReference) throws JsonProcessingException {
      return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, typeReference);
  }
```

And call it in this way:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> data = readJSON3(jsonString, new TypeReference<>(){});
```

This works (`Field1` is being parsed as String), but I would really like to encapsulate all the Jackson stuff like TypeReference in the helper class. This is, I don't want the caller to use TypeReference. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using off-the-shelf libraries for this instead? E.g. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema where you define the schema your data has instead of writing code.

Comment: I think that in my case is a bit overkilling to define an schema, I really want to do it with generics.

Comment: overkill is when you write a ton of your own code to achieve something an off-the-shelf library already does, better to spend your own time on further developing your program =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the article: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast (paragraph 6). There are the limits to use generic types due to runtime nature.

As I see, you can use solution such as:

```
public class Program {
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\n" +
                " \"List\": [\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "   \"Field1\": 1678493915,\n" +
                "   \"Field2\": \"A string\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                " ]\n" +
                "}";
        
        Map<String, List<CustomType>> res = func(json, CollectionCustomType.class);

    }

    private static <T> T func(String json, Class<T> type) throws IOException {
        JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(type);
        return mapper.readValue(json, javaType);

    }


    @Data
    private static class CustomType {

        @JsonProperty("Field1")
        private String field1;

        @JsonProperty("Field2")
        private String field2;
    }
    
    private static class CollectionCustomType extends HashMap<String, List<CustomType>> {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want simple ways without use TypeReference, just consider using `mapper.readTree(json)`.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import java.io.IOException;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    String json = "{\"List\":[{\"Field1\":1678493915,\"Field2\":\"A string\"}]}";
    JsonNode data = mapper.readTree(json);

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(data));
    System.out.println(data.get("List"));
    System.out.println(data.get("List").get(0));
    System.out.println(data.get("List").get(0).get("Field1"));
    System.out.println(data.get("List").get(0).get("Field2"));
}
```

The output will be:

```
{
  "List" : [ {
    "Field1" : 1678493915,
    "Field2" : "A string"
  } ]
}
[{"Field1":1678493915,"Field2":"A string"}]
{"Field1":1678493915,"Field2":"A string"}
1678493915
"A string"
```